# image not showing in mediaSection in Back Office Umbraco Version 8

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm exploring umbraco 8 latest version. I'm trying to create new Image media within surfaceController. My problem is code executes successfully but it doesn't create image in media section.

```
public class ContactFormController : SurfaceController
{
    // GET: Tour
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(TourViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    { 
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string imgPath = @"Path of image file aka TestImage.jpg";

            var ms = Services.MediaService;

            using (var file1 = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var parent = ms.GetRootMedia().FirstOrDefault(); // or -1 for root media object
                var media = ms.CreateMedia("TestImage", parent, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image);

              media.SetValue(Constants.Conventions.Media.File, file1); // save image inside folder
                var mediaSaved = ms.Save(media);
             }

       return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

Here is output:

[image]

Can anyone suggest why image is not loading in mediaSection ?

Comment: What does the vairable 'file' return?

Comment: In given example, Im not using variable 'file'. Instead variable 'file1' is being used.

Comment: You are passing a variable into the method named 'file': HttpPostedFileBase file, it's called.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Yes. I mean variable 'file' is passed in method but never used. My focus is on 'file1' which is created by using imgPath variable. and when this is being saved in mediaSection using umbraco APi...you see empty result as shown in  screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried getting it in the frontend even though it doesn't show? Maybe it's just the preview not working.

Comment: nope. it doesn't work.